# Why does Nexus not download the complete indices and jar file which the Maven Central Repo have?

Tags: maven, nexus

As the picture shows there are many indices in the remote but the local storage just a few, what should I do? Is the problem in the configuration?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nexus downloads the jars that are requested (by Maven builds). So you can build against any jar from MavenCentral but on the first build you need to wait until it is downloaded.

MavenCentral has several thousand GB - it would take ages to download it completely and they will probably block you if you try.

Comment: Thank you very much! In this case,if I want to use some artifact from Nexus,just like the commons-io.jar,should I download it from MavenCentral and upload to my Nexus?In addition to that,Do you have any good ideas to resolve it?because it is very troublesome.

Comment: You do not need to resolve anything. Just build using Maven against your Nexus, and your Nexus will automatically download the requested jars from MavenCentral.

Comment: Thank you very much! Maybe I have some problems with the server network.I has built my project several times，but the Nexus still did not download the jar file.